# Delphi 10.3 Android problem dll fbclient not found (Db firebird,Using Zeos)

Tags: android, firebird, delphi-10.3-rio, zeos

I create Android apps with Delphi Rio 10.3, connection with Zeos, and database is Firebird. On Windows my apps work well, now I want make it to Android. When I finish compiled into my android cellphone, I get error:

> none of the dynamic libraries can be found or is not loadable:
> fbclient25.cll, fbclient.dll ! use TZConnection.LibraryLocation if the
> location is invalid

Is there anybody can help me to solve this?

Comment: You probably have to deploy the FireBird client on the phone.

Comment: First of all, Android doesn't use DLLs, so if something in your code expects actual .dlls, that is not going to work on Android; second, try to include the Firebird client library for Android, e.g. from https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/#Android and reference it in `TZConnection.LibraryLocation`, just be aware that this assumes that Zeos actually works on Android with Firebird.